# serverless deploy Error: Error: Cannot find module './lib/core'

Tags: python, yaml, serverless-framework

I am getting an error on the command serverless deploy and I can't find any documentation on the source of this error. It works on my local machine which means I must have something else installed that makes it work but I cant figure out what.

I am trying to build on AWS.

my serverless.yaml:

```js
service: suqinn-python
app: suquinn-be
plugins:
  - '@serverless/enterprise-plugin'
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-custom-packaging-plugin
  - serverless-python-requirements




package:
  exclude:
    - 'node_modules/**'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  profile: ${opt:profile,"AlexisLefebvre"}
  region: ${opt:region,"eu-west-2"}
  stage: ${opt:stage,"dev"}
  environment:
    STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    REGION: ${self:provider.region}
    DYNAMODB_SECURITIES_TABLE: ${self:custom.DynamoDBSecuritiesTableName}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - dynamodb:PutItem
        - dynamodb:Query
        - dynamodb:Scan
        - dynamodb:GetItem
        - dynamodb:UpdateItem
        - dynamodb:DeleteItem
      Resource: 
        - arn:aws:dynamodb:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:table/${self:custom.DynamoDBTradesTableName}

    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action:
        - s3:GetObject
      Resource: 
        - arn:aws:s3:::*

functions:
  create:
    handler: handler.create
    environment:
      STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    events:
      - http:
          path: form
          method: post
          cors: true
  get:
    handler: handler.get
    environment:
      STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    events:
      - http:
          path: form
          method: get
          cors: true
  delete:
    handler: handler.delete
    environment:
      STAGE: ${self:provider.stage}
    events:
      - http:
          path: form
          method: delete
          cors: true
  
  

custom:
  client: "kkk"
  DynamoDBTradesTableName: ${self:custom.client}-trades-${self:provider.stage}
  s3reportsName: ${self:custom.client}-reports-${self:provider.stage}
```

and my buildspec.yaml:

```js
version: 0.2
#comment
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10
      python: 3.8
    commands:
      - pip install pyjwt
      - pip install pytz
      - pip install pandas_market_calendars
      - npm install serverless -g
      - npm install serverless-pseudo-parameters
      - npm install serverless-custom-packaging-plugin
      - npm install serverless-python-requirements
      - npm install @serverless/enterprise-plugin

  build:
    commands:

      - serverless deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add to your `serverless.yml`

```
package: # Optional deployment packaging configuration
  include: # Specify the directories and files which should be included in the deployment package
    - ./**
  exclude: # Specify the directories and files which should be excluded in the deployment package
    - 'node_modules/**'
```

A better practice is to include only the folders that relevant this the specific lambda function and not all the project files

Taken from:
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

Comment: Thanks Dori for your answer. I have changed my serverless.yaml with package:
  include: # Specify the directories and files which should be included in the deployment package
      - '*'
  exclude:
      - 'node_modules/**'    but I still get the same error. It looks like the custom packaging module needs something I have installed in my node modules that is not reinstalled in my buildspec. I could solve this by removing the custom packaging but then my zip file goes from 500kb to 75MB which is not great.

Comment: @AlexisLefebvre can you show us the import / require statement? 
You using some webpack or other bundle tools?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be coming from the custom-packaging-plugin. Removing the plugin solves that issue but then your package.zip explodes in size which is also a problem. Amending the serverless.yaml to:

```js
service: suqinn-python
app: suquinn-be
plugins:
  - '@serverless/enterprise-plugin'
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters
  - serverless-custom-packaging-plugin
  - serverless-python-requirements




package:
  include:
      - '*'
  exclude:
      - 'node_modules/**'
```

unfortunately still yields the same error:

Error --------------------------------------------------

Error: Cannot find module './lib/core'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object. (/codebuild/output/src448056649/src/node_modules/archiver/index.js:8:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object. (/codebuild/output/src448056649/src/node_modules/serverless-custom-packaging-plugin/lib/index.js:5:18)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at requireServicePlugin (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:27:12)
at pluginsObject.modules.filter.map.name (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:144:20)
at Array.map ()
at PluginManager.resolveServicePlugins (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:141:8)
at PluginManager.loadAllPlugins (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/classes/PluginManager.js:127:40)
at service.load.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/Serverless.js:88:39)
at tryCatcher (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
at Promise._fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:617:21)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
at Promise._fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
at Promise._resolveCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:466:57)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:559:17)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
at Promise._fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
at PromiseArray._resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:127:19)
at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:145:14)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:609:26)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
at Promise._fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
at Promise._resolveCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:466:57)
at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:559:17)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
at Promise._fulfill (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:673:18)
at PropertiesPromiseArray.PromiseArray._resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise_array.js:127:19)
at PropertiesPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/props.js:78:14)
at Promise._settlePromise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:609:26)
at Promise._settlePromise0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
at Promise._settlePromises (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
at _drainQueueStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
at _drainQueue (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
at Async._drainQueues (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)